# net:: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED issue while calling API from React front End

Tags: reactjs

> net:: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I got above issue whenever I hit the API from front end app.

I have tried with CORS policy or Access Control Allow origin but no solution.

I am getting this issue when I call the API and I am able to above error in console.
I am also able to see CORS error.
Is this related to back end development.

Comment: The ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error occurs when a browser can't find the IP address for a website's domain name.
*Flush DNS cache: Clear the DNS cache on your device. Windows will clear and reset your DNS cache files.
*Restart your router: Restart your internet modem or router.
*Disable internet security software: Temporarily disable your firewall and antivirus software.
*Change DNS servers: Change the DNS server used by your computer.
Scan for malware: Malware can cause this error.

Comment: Thanks for the Answers. I will try. BTW. We have the Same name.